# How to encapsulate logic within children like component frameworks?

Tags: f#, websharper, fable-f#, elmish

I'm trying to understand how to create reusable components using the Elmish architecture within F# Bolero by WebSharper (e.g. a reusable validated form input). From all of the examples I've seen, the top level Parent must handle all messages/updates and logic, while children are simply for views. I'm wondering if there's a way around this, whether by having a child handle its own state + messages, and propagating certain messages to the parent (which I've attempted in code below), or if there's another design to handle this.

In my specific case, I'm trying to create a form input component for a users name that validates neither field is empty. I don't like the idea of having a parent handle updating the individual fields FirstName and LastName, it should only care about picking up the Submit message. Handling every message a child produces would results in a ton of boilerplate if you use the child more than once

Note: The code I've provided does not compile as I'm struggling to understand how to implement my intended design

```
open Elmish
open Bolero
open Bolero.Html

module NameInput =
    type Model = { FirstName : string; LastName : string }

    type Message =
        | ChangeFirstName of string
        | ChangeLastName of string
        | Submit of Model

    let update model msg =
        match msg with
        | ChangeFirstName s ->
            { model with FirstName = s}, Cmd.none
        | ChangeLastName s ->
            { model with LastName = s}, Cmd.none
        | Submit m ->
            m, Cmd.ofMsg (Submit m)

    type Component() =
        inherit ElmishComponent<Message, Model>()

        let invalidField s = s <> ""

        override this.View model dispatch =
            let fnClass = if (invalidField model.FirstName) then "invalid" else "valid"
            let lnClass = if (invalidField model.LastName) then "invalid" else "valid"
            div [] [
                label [] [ text "First Name: " ]
                input [ 
                    attr.``class`` fnClass 
                    on.change (fun e -> update model (ChangeFirstName (unbox e.Value))) 
                ]

                label [] [ text "Last Name: " ]
                input [ 
                    attr.``class`` lnClass 
                    on.change (fun e -> update model (ChangeLastName (unbox e.Value))) 
                ]

                button [ on.click (fun _ -> update model (Submit model)) ] [ text "Submit" ]
            ]

type Message =
    | NameSubmitted of NameInput.Message.Submit

type Model = { UserName : NameInput.Model }

let initModel = { UserName = { FirstName = ""; LastName = "" } }

let update msg model =
    match msg with
    | NameSubmitted name ->
        // Greet the user
        { model with UserName = name }, Cmd.none

let view model dispatch =
    concat [
        ecomp<NameInput.Component,_,_> 
            model.Username dispatch
    ]

type MyApp() =
    inherit ProgramComponent<Model, Message>()

    override this.Program =
        Program.mkProgram (fun _ -> initModel, Cmd.none) update view
```

Comment: I don't understand Elmish well enough yet to write a complete answer, but take a look at https://github.com/MangelMaxime/fulma-demo and in particular at its parent-child structure. Each layer of the architecture knows what messages belong to it, and what messages belong to a child layer, and passes messages "down" to the child layers as appropriate. So you don't have to have the parent layer handle all the state. I'm still figuring this all out myself, so you'll do better to read the code than to have me keep rambling about it.

Comment: I guess you can solve this by using external messages (ExternalMsg) as described in https://medium.com/@MangelMaxime/my-tips-for-working-with-elmish-ab8d193d52fd

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @rmunn and @hvester for the references, it helped me get a better understanding of Elmish and was able to come up with a solution. As a reference for anyone else who may stumble across this, here is the solution. InternalMessage does not need to private, it just hides those cases from the main program's update function so one can easily see which messages they need to handle. If it is public though, compiler will give an error if you try to match on an InternalMessage case without first unwrapping the Message into an InternalMessage (so the programmer still easily knows which messages are internal)

```
module NameInput =
    type Model = { FirstName : string; LastName : string }

    type private InternalMessage =
        | ChangeFirstName of string
        | ChangeLastName of string

    type Message =
        | Internal of InternalMessage
        | Submit of Model

    let update msg model =
        match msg with
        | ChangeFirstName s ->
            { model with FirstName = s }
        | ChangeLastName s ->
            { model with LastName = s }

    type Component() =
        inherit ElmishComponent<Model, Message>()

        let invalidField s = s <> ""

        override this.View model dispatch =
            let fnClass = if (invalidField model.FirstName) then "invalid" else "valid"
            let lnClass = if (invalidField model.LastName) then "invalid" else "valid"
            div [] [
                label [] [ text "First Name: " ]
                input [ 
                    attr.``class`` fnClass 
                    on.change (fun e -> dispatch << Internal << ChangeFirstName <| unbox e.Value) 
                ]

                label [] [ text "Last Name: " ]
                input [ 
                    attr.``class`` lnClass 
                    on.change (fun e -> dispatch << Internal << ChangeLastName <| unbox e.Value) 
                ]

                button [ on.click (fun _ -> dispatch <| Submit model) ] [ text "Submit" ]
            ]

type Model = { Name : NameInput.Model }

let initModel = { Name = { FirstName = ""; LastName = "" } }

type Message =
    | NameInput of NameInput.Message

let update message model =
    match message with
    | NameInput ni ->
        match ni with
        | NameInput.Internal i ->
            { model with Name = model.Name |> NameInput.update i}
        | NameInput.Submit n ->
            { model with Name = n }
```